# Persisting Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I am building an MVC 4 intranet site that I would like to have persistent data with in a footer.  I'm going to hold a few basic stats that are unique to each user.  I want this data to persist across all pages during a user's visit to the site.

What is the best best way to persist this data?  A cookie?  It's just a few non-senstive bits of information that will be pulled from AD.  I was thinking hidden fields but that seems a bit cumbersome.

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Cookies or Session Data seem like a quick and easy way to accomplish your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could use sessions for this task, I would caution against. Sessions should be avoided as much as possible.

You can use a child action to build the footer, using AD to get the relevant details, and then render this in your layout. If you're concerned about AD being hit every request to render the footer, then just cache the result.

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    ...

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Footer()
    {
        // query AD and stuff the info in a view model
        return PartialView("_Footer", model);
    }
}
```

Then, in your layout:

```
@Html.Action("Footer", "Foo")
```

Of course, you'll need to move your current footer view code into a partial view, named `_Footer.cshtml` based on this example.

To cache, just prefix the child action with:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom = "User")]
```

`Duration` is in seconds, so the above would cache for an hour. And you'll need the following method added in `Global.asax`:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if (custom == "User")
    {
        if (context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        return null;
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

Comment: Awesome Chris, thanks!  I know what I want to do but I don't know the best way so googling doesn't always work.  OutputCache and ChildActionOnly are new to me and a brief search shows that these seem to be what I am after!  2 quick questions:  Why should sessions be avoided?  What is the method in the Global.asax file supposed to be doing?

Comment: 1) The main reason is that sessions are an anti-pattern. The web is meant to be stateless. That's how the HTTP protocol is designed. Sessions are sometimes necessary, since we live in the some times not pretty real world, but the goal is to avoid them. Also, they function (at least in the recommended pattern) using cookies, which more and more are being blocked by paranoid users (and even ones not so paranoid), and countries such as those in the EU actually require opt-in for cookies. The simplest answer is simply that sessions are too often abused and it's easier to just say avoid them.

Comment: 2) The Global.asax method is satisfying the `VaryByCustom` param. There's no built-in way to vary by user, so you vary by custom, and define what the custom vary, in this case "User", does.